# what is the best way to find available points(merchants) around a point(user) if these points(merchants) use different radius in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geometry

I used `geo_shape` for this problem, want to know if there are some other better ways(faster) to solve this problem, ES version is 6.5.

mapping:

```
{
    "index": {
        "mappings": {
            "merchant": {
                "_all": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "properties": {
                    "delivery_circle": {
                        "type": "geo_shape",
                        "tree": "quadtree",
                        "precision": "50.0m",
                        "distance_error_pct": 0.025
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

document example:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "id": 1,
        "delivery_circle": {
            "coordinates": [ // merchant location, its radius is 4km
                123.456,
                1.2345
            ],
            "radius": "4000m",
            "type": "circle"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_source": {
        "id": 2,
        "delivery_circle": {
            "coordinates": [ // merchant location, its radius is 5km
                123.567,
                1.3456
            ],
            "radius": "5000m",
            "type": "circle"
        }
    }
}
```

search query example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "delivery_circle": {
              "relation": "contains",
              "shape": {
                "coordinates": [ // user location
                  123,
                  1
                ],
                "type": "point"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The geoshape query is designed for this kind of task, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is off topic suggestion, but you can consider using geohash for the same. This can reduce your search time complexity.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash